# Vaadin request filter with filter chain?

Tags: java, servlets, vaadin

Is there a way in Vaadin to hook into a request chain and perform operations around the real request/response cycle with `VaadinSession` provided? Currently I use `javax.servlet.Filter`, but it seems that `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` is set somewhere deeper, and in the filter itself it is unset both before and after `chain.doFilter`().

Comment: Ok, I understood that if I want to sneak into request chain BEFORE ui listeners are handled, I have to extend `VaadinService` and override it's `createRequestHandlers`. Extended class could be then created in overriden `VaadinServlet.createServletService()` method.

Comment: Don't sure if I should close the question

Answer (score 3):

I have found a workaround.
First of all, I can't plug into a request handler chain, as there is no such structure. To simulate it, I have split my code into pre-request and post-request code (It's somewhat OK in my case). I'm doing my pre-request stuff in an ordinary `VaadinRequestHandler` and returning false (for a normal request to proceed). Post-request stuff goes to a `javax.serlvet.Filter` mapped in `web.xml`.

Second, if anybody else is having the same problem, and the code is also splittable using the same pattern, here is the a pre-request (vaadin-side) listing:

```
public class MyVaadinServlet extends VaadinServlet{
    @Override
    protected VaadinServletService createServletService(DeploymentConfiguration deploymentConfiguration) throws ServiceException {
        VaadinServletService service = new VaadinServletService(this,
                deploymentConfiguration){
            @Override
            protected List<RequestHandler> createRequestHandlers() throws ServiceException {
                List<RequestHandler> handlers = super.createRequestHandlers();
                handlers.add((session, request, response) -> {
                    // HERE GOES THE CODE
                    return false;
                });
                return handlers;
            }
        };
        service.init();
        return service;
    }
}
```